# How to create a google formula that does horizontal and vertical search

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In recent weeks, I've been working on creating a Google Sheets formula to help me organize a substantial amount of data, with hundreds of new entries coming in each week. My goal is to establish a dashboard where I can have a list of names in column A (representing search criteria 1) and specific keyword in row 2 (representing search criteria 2, spanning columns I to AU).

The formula I'm striving for should search the cell contents in the database sheet based on these two criteria, effectively performing an XY search to retrieve the exact content I need. It's important to note that all cell contents are in text format.

In the database, the content is dynamic. New entries for search criteria 1 are added twice a year, and for criteria 2, there are weekly updates. The data is currently organized so that the corresponding information for criteria 1 is located in row 1, and for criteria 2, the information is stored in column A.

I have tried MATCH, INDEX, IF, QUERY etc. but somehow I always get an error of any sort resulting to errors or empty cell content due to formula fetching the cell content responding only to the first search criteria.

I would be super happy to have some help how to proceed. I Added some pics for clarification.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1anke.png)
[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI45H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dashboard start in cell N1.

You can try this :

In `O1`, you need all your unique weeks : `=transpose(unique(A2:A))`

In `N2`, you need all your criterias 1 : `=transpose(unique(F1:L1))`. You have to modify the `L1` to get all your criterias.

In `O2`, the formula to get your data from the database :

```
=map(N2:N,
lambda(criteria1,
   map(O1:Q1,
     lambda(criteria2,
       iferror(
         query({A2:A,filter(F2:L,F1:L1=criteria1)},
         "Select Col2 where Col1='"& criteria2 &"' and Col2<>''")
,"")
))))
```

Warning : in the second map formula, the range `O1:Q1` should match all your weeks to work properly.
Not sure it's the best way to solve your problem but results seems to be OK.